# Uniform continuous and bounded set of functions is closed under scalar multiplication

Tags: real-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

$f(x)\in C_{ucb}$ (Uniformly continuous and bounded functions)

Show $cf(x)\in C_{ucb}$

Would it be enough to write:

$\forall \epsilon>0$; $ \exists \delta>0$ such that $|x-y|<\delta \rightarrow|cf(x)-cf(y)|<\epsilon^*$

$|f(x)-f(y)|<\frac{\epsilon^*}{|c|}$; where $c\neq0$ and $\frac{\epsilon^*}{|c|}=\epsilon$

I'm not using my bounded condition.

Comment: I guess you mean $\forall\epsilon>0\exists\delta>0$?

Comment: I think you have your for all and there exists backwards. That said, that seems like enough to show that $cf$ is uniformly continuous. To show that $cf$ is bounded, you'll need to use the fact that $f$ is bounded.

Comment: Hey sorry, I'm still not fluent in math jax so it feels like I'm writing it out with a crayon. Fixed.